# In Visual Studio Code with C#, how do I run an NUnit test in Release mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nunit

I have an NUnit test that fails only in Release config, and not Debug config.

I want to investigate with Visual Studio Code, but I can't figure out how to run the test in Release mode.  I can't seem to find any VSCode dialog to change the mode, nor (surprisingly) any SO questions that address this specifically.

Specifically, I want to click this "Run Test" link and have it run in Release mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the configuration in the `launch.json` file, located in the .vscode folder. The config for running tests should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Unit Tests",
  "type": "dotnet",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<YourProject>.dll",
  "args": [
    "--filter",
    "cat==Unit"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

You need to change the value of the `"program":` field to point to the Release version of your project's DLL file, for example:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Release/<YourProject>.dll"
```

After saving the changes, the "Run Test" link should now run it in Release mode.